# QML how to create different types based on a condition

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I was wondering what's the best way to create a Rectangle, Text or Button based on a condition inside my QML code.

Here's a pseudo code:

```
    import QtQuick 2.0

    Item{
        property string name = "rect" or "text" or "button"
        id:root

        if (name === "rect")
        Rectangle {
            //properties
            parent: root
        }

        else if (name === "text")
        Text {
            //properties
            parent: root
        }

        else if (name === "button")
        Button {
            //properties
            parent: root
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try it with a `Loader`

```
Loader {
    property bool shouldBeText
    Component { id: rect; Rectangle {}}
    Component { id: text; Text {}}
    sourceComponent: shouldBeText ? text : rect
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Loader like "derM" answered, or you "create" all Items and set the visibility:

```
Item{
    property string name = "rect" or "text" or "button"
    id:root

    Rectangle {
        //properties
        visible: root.name === "rect"
    }

    Text {
        //properties
        visible: root.name === "text"
    }

    Button {
        //properties
        visible: root.name === "button"
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is to create an item, you are creating 3 which is an expense of unnecessary resources.

Comment: I have used both techniques. It is a tradeoff between time, space and convenience, especially if you have  interaction between the items.

Comment: @eyllanesc Doesn't the `Loader` solution have the disadvantage of using the JavaScript engine and interpreted as opposed to being compiled? I'm wondering what is the performance overhead of using the `Loader`?

Comment: All solutions use the JavaScript engine under the hood. The Loader has to load (read) the component at runtime, so it has some performance overhead.